# How do I write a code that says: "if I can do this, do this. Otherwise do nothing", in Python 2.7?

Tags: list, python-2.7, if-statement

How do I write a code that says: "if I can do this, do this. Otherwise do nothing", in Python 2.7?

I added the code that is not working below.

```
words = ["glad", "lycklig", "fin", "vacker", "sot", "blomming"]

word_index = words.index("sot")
focus_word = words[word_index]
tre = words[word_index+1]
if words[word_index+2] == True:
    fyra = words[word_index+2]
else:
    print "the list is not long enough"
```

So I want to get the word that is two words after "sot" if there is one. In this case there isn't, and then I just want to skip that command.

Comment: Your `if` clause is not right: `if words[word_index+2] == True:`. That is equivalent to checking if `words[word_index+2]` is equivalent to `boolean` True, which is just... impossible, lol. Try `if words[word_index+2]:`

Comment: Tacocat is right, but I think to keep your logic switch the same way, you want `if words[word_index + 2]:`. Also note that you _must_ indent your print statement correctly. Python cares about whitespace.

Comment: @tyleha My bad, haha! I have edited my comment. Thanks for pointing it out! :3 Reflexive :S

Answer (score 0):

There are two general "philosophies" to avoiding errors in Python code.

One, known as "look before you leap" (LBYL) says that you should check that the values you're operating on are correct before you do anything that relies on that correctness. This is a good approach where the errors are not obvious ones, like exceptions, but rather where you get invalid answers when given invalid input.

For your code, the best way to do this kind of check in your code is to use `if word_index + 2 < len(words)` to directly check if the index you're going to be looking up is too large.

The other design for avoiding errors doesn't actually avoid them completely, rather it lets the errors occur and deals with them afterwards. This is known as "easier to ask forgiveness than permission" (EAFP), and usually involves `try` and `except` blocks in Python.

For your code, you could use this code to catch the `IndexError` that will be raised if `word_index+2` is off the end of the `words` list:

```
try:
    fyra = words[word_index+2]
except IndexError:
    print "No such value"
```

You might need more logic though, since `fyra` won't be defined if you hit the `except` case. You might want to quit with `sys.exit()` or set `fyra` to some default value at the end of the `except` instead of just printing the error message.

Note that it's important to think carefully about what exceptions you're catching in an `except` clause. You don't want to catch all errors (with a bare `except:`) in most cases, since that can hide unexpected errors that really should crash the program and show you the stack trace (so you can fix the bug causing them to occur). It's often best to catch the most specific exception type you can, and wrap your `try` around the smallest block of code you can.